# how to add (for loop) inside jquery data:

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox, loops, for-loop

I have this code to update users data, but I can't write the for loop inside jquery data!!

Is there any way to modify the follwing wrong code to be correctly

```
function DisactiveUser()
{
    var num_checkboxes = document.forms[0].elements.length-1;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "submit/php/users.php?do=disactive",
    data: for(i = 1; i <= num_checkboxes; i++)
          {
            "&chk"  + i + "=" + document.getElementById("check" + i).value +
            "&chkc" + i + "=" + document.getElementById("check" + i).checked +
          }
        success: function(html){
        $("#loading").html(html);
    }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the data string prior to the `$.ajax` call, and then provide that:

```
function DisactiveUser()
{
    var num_checkboxes = document.forms[0].elements.length-1;
    var mydata;

    mydata = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= num_checkboxes; i++)
    {
        mydata +=
            "&chk"  + i + "=" + document.getElementById("check" + i).value +
            "&chkc" + i + "=" + document.getElementById("check" + i).checked;
    }
    mydata = mydata.substring(1);   // Ditch the leading &

    $.ajax({
        type:    "POST",
        url:     "submit/php/users.php?do=disactive",
        data:    mydata
        success: function(html){
            $("#loading").html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `$.map` function

```
data: $.map($('input:checkbox').filter(function() { return /^check\d+/.test(this.id); }), function() {
  var id = this.id.replace(/^[^\d]*(\d+)/, "$1");
  return "chk" + id + "=" + this.value + "&chkc" + id + "=" + this.checked;
}).get().join('&')
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a variable before like this:

```
function DisactiveUser()
{
    var myData = "";
    $(":checkbox").each(function(i) {
      myData += "&chk"  + i + "=" + $(this).val() + 
                "&chkc" + i + "=" + $(this).is(":checked");            
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:  "submit/php/users.php?do=disactive",
      data: myData,
      success: function(html){
        $("#loading").html(html);
      }
    });    
}
```

However, unless you need this specific format server-side, you may want to look at [`.serialize()` to handle this](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Here, to make Pointy happy, here's an array route as well, this will perform better for a high number of checkboxes:

```
var myData = $(':checkbox').map(function() {
  return "chk"  + i + "=" + $(this).val() + 
         "&chkc" + i + "=" + $(this).is(":checked");
}).get().join('&');
```

Comment: LOL! We even used (essentially) the same variable name. You cleaned up the code more, though.

Comment: @T.J. - Would be easier if it didn't take 20 seconds per post at the moment :)

Comment: Guys you should really start building long strings buy making arrays and then joining them - your performance on IE will be way better.

Comment: @Pointy - Only true over about 20 items in this case (yes, I tested :), depends how many checkboxes he's dealing with I suppose.

Comment: well I got in the habit because you never know who's going to abuse the code you write :-)  Plus it's super-handy when you're building a string from something that's already an array, because of course you can do it with `$.map`

Answer (score 0):

```
function DisactiveUser()
{
    var num_checkboxes = document.forms[0].elements.length-1;
    var data = '';

    for(i = 1; i <= num_checkboxes; i++)
    {
       data += "&chk" + i + "=" + $("check" + i).val() +
           "&chkc" + i + "=" + $("check" + i)[0].checked;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "submit/php/users.php?do=disactive",
        data: data,
        success: function(html){
        $("#loading").html(html);
    }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually run my jQuery calls like this:

> jQuery('#time').change(function(){
>           jQuery.post( 'tasks.php?mode=mycompleted', 
>                       { time: jQuery('#time option:selected').attr('id') },
>                       function(xml) { showTasks(xml); }
>           );
>       });

That's just an example of a case where I use jQuery to make an "Ajax" call to a PHP script. Anytime that `#time` gets changed it will post data to tasks.php. The function(xml) segment will call back a javascript function to handle the XML response retrieved from the script.

Hope that helps.